# Get status of service on a remote server

Tags: powershell

I need to find the status of a service on a remote computer. Though I can use the following command:

```
Write-Host (Get-Service -ComputerName "remoteServerName" -Name "serviceName").Status
```

which would give me correct status of service. However I have PowerShell 1.0 installed on the server where i need to run this script. `-ComputerName` parameter doesn't work for PowerShell 1.0. Currently I'm not supposed to install higher version of PowerShell.

Any idea how to get the status of a service in PowerShell 1.0?

Comment: Using a system that supports only Powershell 1.0 hints to not-supported version of Windows. Consider upgrading. If that's not an option, try WMI.

Comment: another option : `sc.exe \\remote_server query servicename `

Comment: @kayasax $PSversiontable returns empty .. as it was introduced in powershell 2.0 and onwards. I tried get-host and it shows version as 1.0

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost (and I can't stress this point enough): If the operating system supports it you should upgrade to *at least* PowerShell v2.0. *No exception.* If the system doesn't support PowerShell 2 or newer it's already out of support and should have been replaced/upgraded months ago.

With that said, you can use either WMI (as suggested by @vonPryz):

```
Get-WmiObject -Computer 'remoteServerName' -Class Win32_Service -Filter "DisplayName='ServiceName'"
```

or `sc.exe` (as suggested by @Kayasax):

```
& sc.exe \\remoteServerName query 'ServiceName'
```

Of these two WMI is the more PoSh approach, as it doesn't require parsing text output.